# Not able to inject jersey resource classes while running junit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, testcase

My code is as follows:

```
Response response = eds.dm(eDR, eR);
```

In dm method I have some thing like this:

```
@Inject
    private EDRE sdfs;
```

But it is not getting injected while running testcase.

Comment: You will not need a dependency injection framework to inject with mockito, but mockito limits you to only one injection strategy (constructor, reflection, setters). Can you provide the parts of your test case (definition and use of the mocks, invocation of the method to be tested).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you have integrated any technology (guice, spring, etc) implementing inversion of control (dependency injection) concept and annotation @Inject works only if there's dependency injection feature in the application.

Comment: i have used jersey for injecting

Comment: Jersey actually is JAX-RS reference implementation framework. It don't have built-in dependency injection feature. But it has a support for DI technologies integration. For more detail you can visit this site: https://jersey.java.net/